# Symfony2 can't connect to remote database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My web application (on ip 10.0.0.240) should connect to a remote database (10.0.0.245) but it try to connect on local's IP (10.0.0.240)

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 10.0.0.245
    database_port: null
    database_name: apps
    database_user: apps
    database_password: ******
```

I double check in config file I have :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
```

I took this settings from a existing application of mine working just fine... but here I have constant error :

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'apps'@'10.0.0.240' (using password: YES)
```

If I try to connect from my local machine it works...
I'v deploy my project using capifony
I'v check on `current/app/confif/parameters.yml` and `share/app/config/parameters.yml` they are the same and they are good ...

### EDIT

I'm using symfony 2.2.6

Comment: Try dumping your parameters via console on the remote machine, that you can see if %database_host% has maybe the wrong values. I guess that capifony is already clearing the cache during deploys?

Comment: @m0c i'm on ssh on production server, usin php app/console i can't find how to dump parameters ?

Comment: The database server doesn't allow connections from the user apps and the machine 10.0.0.240

Comment: php app/console container:debug --parameter=database_host

Comment: sorry @m0c, It says that "--parameter" option doesn't exist

Comment: What other options do you have with container:debug (Note: don't run it with --env=prod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my user(apps) was not allowed to connect from 10.0.0.240

Pazi was right after all !

It was due to missunderstanding of msql error message

I've change the privilege for apps user to connect from 10.0.0.240 and everything works fine...

Comment: @Pazi I have to wait 2 days ... but I will :)